# What are the volume-preserving diffeomorphisms of hyperbolic space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

**What are the volume-preserving diffeomorphisms of $d$-dimensional hyperbolic space (in say the hyperboloid model)?**

In particular, I'm especially interested in: **what are the volume-preserving diffeomorphisms which map totally geodesic submanifolds to totally geodesic submanifolds?**

In Euclidean space we have the invertible linear transformations with unit determinant.  I'm looking for an analog in hyperbolic space.

Are there any volume-preserving diffeomorphisms which map totally geodesic submanifolds to totally geodesic submanifold which are not isometries?

This is most likely well-studied, however I am unable to find a clean answer.

Comment: There are much more volume preserving diffeomorphisms than the ones you say even in Euclidean space right? For example for any smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the function $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y+f(x))$ gives a volume preserving diffeo of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or in general any diffeo whose derivative has unit determinant at each point works.

Comment: Good point. I edited the question to take this into account.

Comment: The edited question is answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338075/geodesic-preserving-diffeomorphisms-of-constant-curvature-spaces.